# What is the best way of retrieving one to one relational data in Android?

Tags: android, mobile-country-code

The question is when I get the country sim code from android device I want to get the country number from a database or from a text file. Unfortunately as I know (so sadly) We cannot get a country code from the api as number like 44 31 33 whatever the country.In this case I want to use a table and match the country code with the number and use the number. for example, if the getSimCountryCode() returns gb one method will go and check the database and find +44 country code. So what  do you think the best way and lightweight way of doing this? Do you think I should use sqlite and put the one to one data there and retrieve the data from database or is there a better way of dong it as a separate string file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on how large your country code table will be.  If it is small, then loading it into something like an in-memory Map might be fine.  Otherwise, SQLite will be the way to go if it is a very large dataset.

Comment: as big as how many countries there are. there must be away to get country code as a number from android device.

Comment: That doesn't look like much data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_country_codes.  I don't see an API which will do it for you.